# in one column one div of another height flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox, display

I need to create one div which have a 120px height. I can use only `display: flex`. I can't use float. I can use only div.

I've got code, but I have no idea how to do it:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  width: 240px;
}

.flex-container>div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
</div>
```

The final effect must be this:

[image: click]

Comment: You can use a table instaed?

Comment: I can use only div

Answer (score -2):

It is easier doing this with CSS grid. Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <style>
  .grid-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 50px);
  }
  .grid-item{
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .bigger-cell{
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: span 2;
    grid-column-start: 4;
  }

  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item">1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">3</div>
    <div class="grid-item bigger-cell">4</div>
    <div class="grid-item">5</div>
    <div class="grid-item">6</div>
    <div class="grid-item">7</div>
    <div class="grid-item">9</div>
    <div class="grid-item">10</div>
    <div class="grid-item">11</div>
    <div class="grid-item">12</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but I can use only display: flex